# issue while converting xsd to java pojo when attribute name="value"

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

How can i convert the below piece of xsd to java pojo. I tried using the JAXB project way using eclipse to convert it but its giving me error( `Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.`). I think its because i have name="value" and its conflicting somewhere.

```
 <xs:complexType name="demo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java class representing that complex type might be something like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "demo")
public class Demo {
    private String valueAttr;
    private String valueContent;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    public String getValueAttr() {
        return this.valueAttr;
    }

    public void setValueAttr(String valueAttr) {
        this.valueAttr = valueAttr;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValueContent() {
        return this.valueContent;
    }

    public void setValueContent(String valueContent) {
        this.valueContent = valueContent;
    }

}
```

Class name, fields names, and method names can be changed to whatever you want them to be, since the XML names are explicitly given in the annotations.

To see it working, use this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {

    @XmlElement
    private Demo demo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setValueAttr("this is the attr value");
        demo.setValueContent("this is the element content");
        Test test = new Test();
        test.demo = demo;

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(test, System.out);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
    <demo value="this is the attr value">this is the element content</demo>
</test>
```

Comment: This is not working when am using jackson api in spring to unmarshall it. I am sending xml in POST to spring rest controller and it not populating with anything.

Comment: @ProgrammerBoy This should work, so if it doesn't, then you did something wrong. Since you haven't shown what you've done, it's impossible for us to identify what you did wrong. This question has been answered. If you have another question, create a new one, and include all relevant information, e.g. the actual payload of the POST, the JABX annotated classes, and the Spring MVC method for handling the POST.

Comment: thanks for taking effort to answer it...i appreciate. Am getting "JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "" " error message. I will create a separate question with details later.

Comment: JSON parse error when processing XML? That should be a clue, don't you think. Did the client give the correct content type on the POST? Did you give the correct content type in the Spring annotation?